# Have you had a chance to update to Angular 15 and use it with Angular CLI 15

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I've updated Angular to v15 as well as Angular CLI. Now when attempting to launch project i receive this error:

> This version of CLI is only compatible with Angular versions ^14.0.0,
> but Angular version 15.0.0 was found instead.

I even tried `Angular CLI 15.1.0-next.3` but no luck.

Does it mean that CLI isn't compatible with Angular 15 yet?

Comment: Is there any package of angular left if you execute ng update?

Answer (score 0):

You're probably use the `ng` command from your global node_modules.

Either this

```
npm i -g @angular/cli@latest
ng serve
```

Or this

```
npx ng serve
```

Should work.